# How to make a container div stretch vertically to fit a table in IE?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm having trouble with a fairly simple three column layout where there is a container div which contains several other divs, some of which are basically present for design, the main one of which contains a table. So the relevant source looks a bit like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left-side-decoration">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="right-side-decoration">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="content">
    <table id="datatable">
      <thead><th>Title</th></thead>
      <tr><td>Content Row 1</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Content Row 2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Content Row 3</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="footer-decoration">
</div>
```

For the design to work I need the overall height to be at least the height of the browser window. So I have a stylesheet that works like this:

```
#wrapper
  {
     height: 100%;
  } 
#left-side-decoration
  {
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: 154px;
      background-color: red;
  }
#right-side-decoration
  {
      float: right;
      width: 1em;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: red;
  }
#content
  {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #6f9dd9;
    margin-left: 154px;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
#footer-decoration
  {
    height: 3em;
    clear: both;
    background-color: green;
  }
```

Now this works out fine in Firefox and often in IE, but `datatable` can get taller than the height of the browser window. When that happens, it vanishes under the `footer-decoration` div and reappears below it for Internet Explorer users.

I have tried changing the overflow settings, but I don't want to lose the content at the bottom of the page or have a scrollbar, what I really want is for the page to be *at least* the height of the browser window but maybe a little taller. The obvious thing for this would be to use `min-height` but when I change the height of the wrapper to use that both `left-side-decoration` and `right-side-decoration` shrink down to a few pixels high and neither using a 100% height or a 100% min-height seems to change it.

So if I use `height: 100%` my table falls out of the bottom of the page in IE, if I use `min-height: 100%` my side panels shrink away to nothing. I assume that the min-height problem relates to the divs floating and so being out of the page flow, but I don't see a good way to fix it. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Every durable solution I've seen to this involves Javascript that will watch the browser window's size and update the size of the relevant div tags to fit properly.

You would need to handle the initail page load as well as the "resize" event.  You may also need to deal with recalculating the sizes after postbacks.

Comment: Or, I guess, just switch to a table based design? I mean, it's horrible but if it works...